# Pass job parameter to gradle task in scripted pipeline

Tags: gradle, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

i'm trying to convert my freestyle job in a scripted pipeline, i'm using gradle for the build and artifactory to resolve my dependecies and publish artifacts.

My build is parametraized with 3 params and in freestyle job when i configure *Invoke gradle script* I have the checkbox *Pass all job parameters as System properties* and in my 
project.gradle file I use the params with System.getProperty() command.

Now implementing my pipeline I define the job parameters, I have these like enviromnent variables in the Jenkinsfile but can I pass this params to the gradle task?

Following the official tutorial to use Artifactory-Gradle plugin in pipeline I run my build with :

```
buildinfo = rtGradle.run rootDir: "workspace/project/", buildFile: 'project.gradle', tasks: "cleanJunitPlatformTest build"
```

Can I pass params to gradle build and use in my .gradle file?

Thank's

Comment: In gradle, get environment variables using System.getenv. E.g. `System.getenv('PATH')`. And in your Pipeline job you either define those variables assigning something like ${params.xXx} or you are using `environment { .. }` in your Jenkinsfile.

Comment: I tried this methods but not work, I defined in my jenkinsfile the env variabiles with `withEnv(['FORCE_HTML_REPORT = false')` and in gradle `System.getenv('FORCE_HTML_REPORT')`  but it return null

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. If using sh ''' then switch that to sh """ to get the expanded values

Jenkinsfile

```
  #!/usr/bin/env groovy

  pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(name: 'firstParam', defaultValue: 'AAA', description: '')
        string(name: 'secondParam', defaultValue: 'BBB', description: '')
        string(name: 'thirdParam', defaultValue: 'CCC', description: '')
   }

   stages {
        stage ('compile') {
             steps {
                sh """
                    gradle -PfirstParam=${params.firstParam} -PsecondParam=${params.secondParam} -PthirdParam=${params.thirdParam} clean build
                sh """
             }
        }
    }
  }
```

and inside your build.gradle you can access them as

```
def firstParam = project.getProperty("firstParam")
```

You can also use SystemProperty with -D prefix as compared to project property with -P. In that case you can get the value inside build.gradle as

```
def firstParam = System.getProperty("firstParam")
```

Comment: what if firstParam / secondParam contains spaces? it will mess up the command.